# Django 2.1.4 Registration Form + Login Page

Tags: python, django

Hi I am new to Django and need help with registration form and login. I am able to register and able to see the user credentials registered under admin register model. However, i tried to take the user-credentials in the database and then want to do a login, but unable to do so. Can someone help please.

models.py

```
class register(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.username)
```

Views.py

```
#register 
def registerForm(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.POST.get('name') and request.POST.get('username') and request.POST.get('password') and request.POST.get('occupation'):
                reg = register()
                reg.name = request.POST['name']
                reg.username = request.POST['username']
                reg.password = request.POST['password']
                reg.occupation = request.POST['occupation']
                reg.save()

            return render(request, 'login.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'register.html')
#Login
def Login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('username') and request.POST.get('password'):
            usr_login = register()
            usr_login.username = request.POST['username']
            usr_login.password = request.POST['password']
            usr_login.user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if usr_login.user:
                login(request, usr_login.user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/forum/')
            else:
                error = "Username and Password are invalid. Please try again."
                return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

login.html

```
<form method="post" action="/forum/">
                          {% csrf_token %}
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                                <input type="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username" required="required">
                             </div>

                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" required="required">
                             </div>
                             <div class="row">
                              <div class="col" align="center">
                                 <div class="form-group form-check">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Remember me
                                    </label>
                                 </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="login">Submit</button><br><br>
                                    Not yet registered? <a href="/registeration/">Register Here.</a>
                     </form>
```

urls.py

```
# login
url(r'^login/$', views.Login, name='login'),

# register
url(r'^registeration/$', views.registerForm, name='registeration'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to authenticate the user using the django builtin authentication backend but you are not using the django User model. In your case you have to create custom authentication logic. I strongly suggest you to hash the user's password.

If you want to use the builtin auth framework you check out the documentation for more information https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/

Comment: is it possible to dont use the django built-in authentication backend and just create a new simple model to store and use the user credentials for the login page?

Comment: Yes it is. You just have to define your own authenticate method.

Comment: Because I wanted something simple, i tried reading the django documentation but could not understand. I created a model for the registration and once user click submit button at the the registration form page i have stored it into the database. However, from here how can i do the login function?

Comment: `def custom_login(username, password): 
    try:
        return register.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
    except register.DoesNotExists:
        return False
`
I don't recommend you to use your own because you will have to write alot boilerplate code. You will have to manage the session on your own, create authorization mechanism etc ... If you really want to have custom user model just use the django way for it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model.

Comment: Thank you so much I managed to implement the built in authentication !!

Comment: Well done. Its always better to use the built in methods.

Comment: I wanted to do a auto-logged out after I leave the page. Because I am trying to create a web application that only for the forum section need to login to post reply and posts. But if I don’t click the logout button I will still be logged into the forum.